# How to analyse Signalling flow between threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, simulator

I want to analyse the signalling flow between threads of network application simulator.  Is there any tool that helps to generate signalling flow between threads?
The application is implemented in C.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Tool recommendations are explicitly off-topic. And I have no idea what "signalling flow between threads" is supposed to mean. Sounds like the tool you are looking for is a debugger.

Comment: for uCs I use  https://percepio.com/tz/freertostrace/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=google_freertos_ad&utm_term=freertos&utm_content=ad68&gclid=CjwKCAjwmqKJBhAWEiwAMvGt6J50u8wAlqvn8qfHzri_OIfv5fVA8ZTadBXbxO6LtCghzJ_kMgzgBxoC7RQQAvD_BwE

Comment: signaling flow is Communication Flow view which shows a visual graph over the process interactions, signals and pipes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is an Interaction graph between threads, like UML sequence graph.